# Offline verification in Android application

Tags: java, android, offline, verification

I decided to create an application for our technicians in our company. This app sending email through gmail SMTP with some extra fields as working time, etc ... Its working, and Im happy :)

But, I need to distribute this app widely in our company, that means, that I need some sort of verification, that app is in THIS technician mobile phone.

My idea is to store some "verification numbers" in code, so the technician, that run app for the first time, will be asked for enter unique number to identify the person, who is using it.

My question is :

**Is there any way how is this possible to code?**

For example, the app runs for the first time, then the popup in-app window will be displayed, askking for the unique number. Then it will be paired with telephone number and technician name.

Like : `if a=1234 then String phone = 987654 and String nameoftech = Bill Gates`

Comment: Authentication is tricky to get right. Essentially you would want a service that you can trust to route the emails through and authenticate against. Trusting any secrets stored on the device is usually bad.

Comment: This question is for offline verification... Is this verification supposed to happen without internet connection? because that would make it difficult to add new users.

Comment: @kevswanberg Authentication of emails is done, I need only authentication of user of app, not user of email ... email is still the same, only content depends on ehat technician write to the test field :)

Comment: @doubleA maybe crazy idea, but I know the range and name of users, that will be able to use this app, it will be only for closed group of user, so I can hardcode it to the app. Verification will be offline, that typed number will becompared with numbers hardcoded in app

Comment: problem here is if you hardcode those numbers in the app all i need to do is decomplie the app to get those numbers to 'Login'.

Comment: @doubleA my coworkers will never do that, because they dont understand that magic of decompiling and bypassing this Code :D

Comment: Your coworkers might not do that. But does not mean someone else will not. Its really what you want to balance. Security vs time to code/ease of use.

Comment: @doubleA you are right ... but this time, I only need that simple solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Really what you are looking for is authentication. But having this type of information hardcoded is not a common use case so you will probably not find an example anywhere of exactly what you had in mind. A better option might be to use basic [drop-in firebase authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui). Fairly easy to implement and you could set up users in the firebase console.

Otherwise just generate some random numbers tied to each user and hardcode them in the app. Then give them that number as their login. They enter in in an EditText you check if it matches hardcoded values.

Comment: still confusing :D ... I know, you are heading for security, and your tip is very helpfull, but, if it is possible, can you point me for some example of solution that I looking for ... you know what I think from our comments :) ... and user authentication will be set only with firtst run, not everytime the app is running :)